# Android ExoPlayer get default selected audio / subtitle tracks

Tags: android, audio, default-value, exoplayer

I am trying to get the default selected audio/subtitle track after the player is initialized.

When I change the subtitle/audio I am creating an override and pass that to the player which contains trackIndex, trackGroupId, but the player has no (or I can't find) public function which returns the default selected track or track index (afterload).

I also checked the possible formats but I didn't see any "selected" or "default" attribute on them.

I saw that SimpleExoPlayer has the renderers array and every renderer contains the selected Format, but unfortunately, this is not accessible programmatically.

Is there any solution to identify which tracks have been selected by the player? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

TrackGroup[].formats[].selectionFlags is what I was looking for.